# Fetching min of current date from a lot of date strings in a single column

Tags: sql, oracle

In a specific column I have grouped all the dates with timestamp sorted ASC as a string with ; seperator and that column can contain 1 - 50 date strings. From the date strings I have, i need to fetch the latest dates Min value.

Sample, (let's assume sysdaye date is 07/25/2019).

```
07/24/2019 12:02:44; 
07/24/2019 12:03:56; 
07/24/2019 10:02:44; 
07/25/2019 12:02:44; 
07/25/2019 12:03:56.
```

I am not certain the date value I wanted comes in the certain position and I know it can be done with RegEx. Can someone give me a RegEx for this or a suitable suggestion to do this any other way in Oracle SQL?

Comment: Storing dates in strings is a really, really, really bad idea.

Comment: You won't say that when you see my requirement and approach to it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all your dates are sorted and have exactly one format, here's regex solution

```
select
    dates,
    regexp_substr(
        dates,
        concat(
            regexp_substr(regexp_substr(dates, '(\d|\s|/|:|-)+$'), '(\d|/|:|-)+'),
            '(\d|\s|/|:|-)+')
    ) as max_date_min_datetime
from
    <table_name>
```

Comment: Hi Y.K, You are a Rockstar of regular expressions. Can you pl tell what is done so that I can try to understand it.. Please!!

Comment: `regexp_substr(dates, '(\d|\s|/|:|-)+$')` -- this portion of code finds last (`$` symbol cares about it) combination of digits (`\d`), space symbols (`\s`), slash, colon or hyphen than meets 1 or more times (`+` symbol); next portion of code, with `'(\d|/|:|-)+'` finds first portion of symbols without spaces in part, that previous regexp return (note, that i exclude `\s` from expression); then you concatenate returned date with `'(\d|\s|/|:|-)+'`, so you get string like `07/25/2019(\d|\s|/|:|-)+`, which finds first occurrence of this date with time, which is in your case, the least datetime